# Centering recursive pascals triangle in java?

Tags: java, math, recursion, user-input

I've got the output of Pascal's triangle down, the numbers are right and everything but the formatting has to be right in the output, (i.e., centered). How can I achieve this? We haven't learned any 'System.out.format' type coding, any solutions I've seen involve that.

**Program 1**

```
public class Pascal
{
   private int r;

   public Pascal(int numRows)
   {
   r=numRows;
   }


    public static int recrPascal(int row, int col)
    {
        int val1, val2, result = 0;
        if (row == 0 || col == 0 || row == col + 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        val1 = recrPascal(row - 1, col - 1);
        val2 = recrPascal(row - 1, col);

        return val1 + val2;
    }

      public static void printPascalRecursion(int maxRows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= maxRows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(recrPascal(i, j) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();

        }
    }
     }
```

**Program 2**

```
import java.util.*;
public class PascalDriver
{
   public static void main(String [] args)

   {
      Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter value for n: ");
      int n = kbReader.nextInt();
      Pascal a = new Pascal(n);


      a.printPascalRecursion(n);




   }


}
```

Comment: How would you do it by hand, in a basic text editor? Forget about the code for a second and think about what your actual goal is.

Comment: Consider counting the number of digits in the biggest number. Substract from that number the number of digits of each computed number, and divide the result by 2. You must then place the division result number of space before and after the computed number you used in this operation.

Comment: Given that you know the number r of rows, you know how long the final row should be, r.  Imagine Pascals triangle inside of a square.  How many spaces should you be printing at the beginning of each row?

Comment: Using the centering command and spaces in between the numbers? I realize that I could probably do it using spacing here, but also keep in mind that I have it based on user input and the user could potentially input any number which I'm not sure how to work around.

Answer (score 1):

So you Want the output like

$$$1

$$1 1

$1 2 1

and so on...

**Consider $ as space.**

Add one for loop which decreases no of spaces from MAX(No of rows) to Zero
in "printPascalRecursion(int maxRows)".

Hope You got it..

Comment: For a specific number, multiplication by 11 can increase the number by 2 digits instead of just 1. Not sure if OP needs to go that high though. Still a thing worth considering :)

Answer (score 1):

add this method to your class

```
public static void print(char c,int no){
        if(no<1)
            return;
        System.out.print(c);
        print(c,no-1);
}
```

when you loop through the first loop, put a call to this method with parameters (' ',row-i)
This would atleast make it a bit neater. Experiment with the spacing to get better results.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= maxRows; i++)
        {
            print(' ',row-i); 
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(recrPascal(i, j) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();

        }
```

Also increase the " " in

```
System.out.print(recrPascal(i, j) + " ");
```

to make it look better